# Refresh page / result after Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax

So I have a php file printing out result in a table from my database and when i mark a result using checkbox, it sends this variable to a new page deleting it.  The problem is, in the same page as he Jquery code is in, all the result is displayed, and I want the result to be updated after something is deleted. Tried using window.location.reload(true); in the Ajax code, but now it only delete one result at the time. Some way to relode the page or refresh the result?

In my sakerselect.php: here it print out all result in my database containg checkbox:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  WHERE Kundenr LIKE '".$_GET['kundenr'] ."'ORDER BY  CAST(Status as varchar) DESC ";

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
   if( $stmt == false){
       die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), tue) );
   }


echo "<table id='div2' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th></th><th>Saksnr</th><th>Saksinfo</th><th>Eier</th> <th>Status</th></tr>";


while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) 
{


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='id[]' class='toedit' value='"   . $row[0] . "'></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
```

sakerselect is included in my KundeDisplay.php page. 
KundeDisplay.php is also containing this ajax code sending the marked values to sakerdelete.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#deletesaker').on('click', function () {
        var ids = [];
        $(".toedit").each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                ids.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        if (ids.length) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "php/sakdelete.php",
                data: {
                    id: ids
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("p").text(data);  
                    window.location.reload(true);

                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please select items.");
        }
    });
</script>
```

In my sakdelete.php file:

```
include 'connect-database.php';

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id) {

    $sql = "DELETE FROM Saker Where Saksnr = $id";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
    if ($stmt == false) {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can delete one record at a time by this method

If You want to delete two are more record at a time
try this ....

http://www.codexworld.com/delete-multiple-records-from-mysql-in-php/